# Making a text box in mvc readable from model

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a model which I have binded with a view having text boxes. Now their are certain text boxes which i want to make read only and that to from the model class.
So any suggestions how can i make them read only from the  model class.

Comment: The Model and View are seperate collections of relating objects. You will break seperations of concerns if you mix them.

Comment: You down voted me fine ... these votes don't matter to me also i m here to learn n gain some thing new so it was just a query asked. Thanks for the solution.

Comment: I didnt down vote you. The comment was to highlight the 'why use mvc anyway?'. If you wonder, you wont get much benefit from MVC.

Comment: readonly property work if we write  in our model its just that we need to add a piece off code in EditorTemplate. When we write read only then metadata property is called. if we write the code in editor template then  also the read only property is added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer:
the View is something like

```
<div>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>@Html.LabelFor(x => x.Name)</td>
            <td>@Html.EditorFor(x => x.Name)</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>@Html.LabelFor(x => x.DOB)</td>
            <td>@Html.EditorFor(x => x.DOB)</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>@Html.LabelFor(x => x.Address)</td>
            <td>@Html.EditorFor(x => x.Address)</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

My ViewModel is:

```
public class SampleModel
    {
        [EnableForRole]
        public String Name { get; set; }

        [EnableForRole]
        public DateTime DOB { get; set; }

        [EnableForRole]
        public String Address { get; set; }
    }
```

And the custom Metadata property is like:

```
public class EnableForRoleAttribute : Attribute, IMetadataAware
    {

        public void OnMetadataCreated(ModelMetadata metadata)
        {
            var toEnable = IsAccessible(metadata.PropertyName);
            metadata.IsReadOnly = !toEnable;
        }
        private bool IsAccessible(String actionName)
        {            
            return HttpContext.Current != null && HttpContext.Current.User != null && HttpContext.Current.User.IsInRole(roleName); //if you use MembershipProvider
        }
    }
```

And now finally you should add the partial view (String.cshtml) in EditorTemplate folder like:

```
@if (ViewData.ModelMetadata.IsReadOnly)
{
    @Html.TextBox("", ViewData.TemplateInfo.FormattedModelValue,
        new {  @readonly = "readonly" })                                     
}
else
{
    @Html.TextBox("", ViewData.TemplateInfo.FormattedModelValue) 
}
```

Thats all.

Enjoy.

Answer (score 1):

`ReadOnly` isn't working in MVC 2 or MVC 1, but it is working in 3 & 4 (beta).

From model you can use as below:

```
 [ReadOnly(true)]
 public bool IsAdmin { get; set; }
```